# JS prototype.namespace for separate file issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, prototype

I've just started trying to get my head around the prototype paradigm to make a jquery plugin.

My code like this works:

```
(function(window, $){

    var Remote = function(elem, options) {

        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.options = options;

        this.p = [];

    };

    Remote.prototype = {
        defaults: {
            message: 'Hello world!'
        },
        init: function() {
            this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

            ...
        },
        findPath: function() {

            var t = this.p.length;

            ...

        }
    };

    Remote.prototype.constructor = Remote;
    Remote.defaults = Remote.prototype.defaults;

    $.fn.remote = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new Remote(this, options).init();
        });
    };

})(window, jQuery);
```

So now I'm trying to make it a little more modular, with the ability to split into multiple files (please correct me if I'm going about any of this wrong):

```
var Remote = function(elem, options) {

    this.elem = elem;
    this.$elem = $(elem);
    this.options = options;

    this.p = [];

};

Remote.prototype = {
    defaults: {
        message: 'Hello world!'
    },
    init: function() {
        this.config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

        ...
    }
};

// I'd like to put this object into path.js
Remote.prototype.path = {
    find: function() {

        var t = this.p.length;
        // this.p is undefined

        ...

    }
};

Remote.prototype.constructor = Remote;
Remote.defaults = Remote.prototype.defaults;

(function(window, $){

    $.fn.remote = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new Remote(this, options).init();
        });
    };

})(window, jQuery);
```

By namespacing within `Remote.prototype` I appear to have lost scope with `this`.

Q1 - where has `this` gone?
Q2 - is this the best way to modularise my code so I can break it into different files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly broad questions so here's some bullet points

1. Try declaring remote like this

   function Remote() {
    ...
   }

This sets your Remote function in window (the top level "this") so you will have window.remote.

Initialise your variables in the constructor function.

Create an instance of your object using new and then manipulate that instance.

You need to call from within the remote instance or "this" will default to the window object,
You can get around this using call, apply or bind.

Check out this link for more in-depth explanations
http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html

2 Check out self-executing functions for modularity. For instance you could do something like

```
(function myPrivateFunction() {
...
})()
```

This isolates your scope for the private function and avoids polluting the global namespace. I'd strongly recommend checking out John Resig's book "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja"

Comment: Thanks for the link. This stuff is pretty confusing! It seems clear enough, it's just nothing like what I've been reading about jQuery plugins....

Comment: If anyone else is interested, I think this is the clearest explanation: http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/